# How can i add simple code in <head> only in posts by function.php

Tags: plugins, php

there are many plugin which help  me to add code to  but it add on whole website on every page. Yoast Seo allos me to add code in head for specific post. But can i add code on all post by function.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform simple check to make sure, the post type is post; before executing actual code.

**For example:**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_custom_style_for_posts');
function load_custom_style_for_posts(){

   global $post_type;

   if( 'post' == $post_type ){
      echo "<style>blahblah</style>";
   }

};
```

Place this code inside `functions.php`

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: MY goal ist to add this code in <head>  on post. How can i do it with your code?
<style>blabla</style>

Comment: I've updated answer, use that code in `functions.php` and it will work. And, don't forget to accept the answer! :)